Can an image be inserted inside a Donut Chart in Google Sheets?
I am trying to create some trackers in Google Sheets and would like to add some images for visualization.
I want to achieve something like this but unsure if it is possible with Google Sheets.
https://i.sstatic.net/EeU6zeZP.png
Would appreciate any input. Thank you
I have no coding background but thought it might be possible with a script.

The question is not doable with Google sheet built in functions, @user27425627 I think this is the correct answer, And I suggest that it was posted as Answer.

If its just some cosmetic appearance thing you are going for, You can insert the image manually (over the cells) + make the chart background transparent to overlay it on the image https://i.sstatic.net/LRJtOUod.png

Short answer: it can't. Not in a simple way: certainly not within Google Sheets, and not even in a script using Apps Script's built-in functions.
What you would probably have to do: generate the donut chart as usual; then, in a separate HTML file, create an image element that follows the chart around using a script. It's certainly not impossible, but if you have no coding background, it's going to be as quick and easy as going through Heidegger's Being and Time.
For reference:

here is a non-answered question from more than four and a half years ago, asking basically the same thing;
here are simple examples of pie charts customised via script;
here is exactly what options can be customised.

EDIT - If the chart is not meant to move, as rockinfreakshow suggested in the comments:

if it's just some cosmetic appearance thing you are going for, you can insert the image manually (over the cells) and make the chart background transparent to overlay it on the image. See this example.


Yes, it's mostly for cosmetic purposes. Anyway, thanks so much for your input. I'll be sticking to using a normal chart, then. :)
